# How to confirm the different mobile platforms with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, screen-size

I have been working this WP-theme with Bootstrap, but for some reason it shows the same on iPhone and iPad despite I've been adding different sizes. When I check iPhone's screen size for web browsing, it's 320 x 480, but Bootstrap interprets it as 640x960 screen. Yes, I could go and change the Bootstrap settings, but then it would affect all the possible screens and I rather want to have own setting for actually small screens than compromise all the other screens as well. I'm certain I'm doing something wrong since on Bootstrap site, the different cols for screens do work, but I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check is there view port meta tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

and also check the media-query and col's whether it's correct or not.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was missing!